# Google OAuth reducing scopes

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-authentication

As part of Google's security review of apps that have access newly labeled restricted scopes it was suggested that we update our scopes to a few scopes which are still restricted but are more limited. So, we compiled and submitted an update to our scopes now our app is no longer verified and has to go back through a verification process. In the interim, now our new users when connecting to their Google accounts with our service are presented with very intimidating warnings about the application now being verified.

Does anyone have advice on how to proceed with this? Feels wrong for adjusting to reduced scopes to result in this behavior.

Comment: This isn't a great question for the SO community, but I was forced here by the Google Cloud Platform support team

Answer (score 1):

The OAuth Application verification team isn't a support team that can be reached, until they reach out to you. Make sure you've followed the appropriate steps:

- You've submitted the verification form.
- You or the project owner have received messages from the verification team. Then you can address any questions from there.

Most of the answers regarding the verification process you're looking for can be answered by reading through the [FAQ](https://support.google.com/cloud/answer/9110914) .